# Spring security logout goes to j_spring_security_logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, logout, spring-3

In my web application when I tries to logout it goes to `j_spring_security_logout` instead of the given page.
In my `spring-security.xml` page i have added

`<logout logout-success-url="/login" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />`

The problem is this worked earlier when I used spring security **3.1.4.RELEASE** version.
Now I'm using **3.2.2.RELEASE**

I've tried the following also. Didn't work

`<logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />`

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/transaction-view"
        always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/invalidSession.htm">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" /> <!--this will throw error to second login attempt -->
    </session-management>
    <!-- <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" /> -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customSecurityService"
    class="com.fg.monitoringtool.web.security.SecurityService"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="com.fg.monitoringtool.web.security.PasswordEncoderMD5"></beans:bean>


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customSecurityService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>

</authentication-manager>
```

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Could you post your full Spring-Security configuration?

Comment: What is your HTML code for logout? Do you have CSRF protection enabled?

Comment: @holmis83 yes, its CSRF protection enabled. Link is 
<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />">

Comment: Try 
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout"/>

Comment: @geoand not working, still goes to j_spring_security_logout

Comment: When you hit /logout from the browser, what happens?

Comment: It goes to http://localhost:8080/test-app/j_spring_security_logout and with a HTTP status 404.

I want it to go to http://localhost:8080/test-app/logout

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you have Spring Security CSRF protection enabled, you must logout with POST:

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was the problem. Because of CSRF enable i cant access links directly. Your solution is working. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I was working on this for ~half of hour. I didn't know why it 's not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to use default logout url would be

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="j_spring_security_logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Tested an not working. I will not downvoted it because is maybe my security configuration, but with the accepted solution is working