# Spring Logout not working and redirecting

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, logout

I have the following JSF Page:

```
<h:form>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <b:navBar brand="TEST" brandHref="#" inverse="true">

        <p:lightBox styleClass="menucolored">

            <p:commandLink id="logout"
                           type="button"
                           action="/j_spring_security_logout"
                           value="Log Out" ajax="false"
                           styleClass="menucolored"/>
        </p:lightBox>
    </b:navBar>
</h:form>
```

Spring Security xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/pages/Login.xhtml"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?error=1"
                default-target-url="/pages/Home.xhtml"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                username-parameter="j_username"
                password-parameter="j_password"/>

    <!-- On logout success load the login page -->
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/Login.xhtml" />

    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>
```

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tried replacing the command link with

```
<h:outputLink value="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">logout</h:outputLink>
```

or

```
<h:outputLink value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">logout</h:outputLink>
```

Still no luck. When I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: Which version of spring-security you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
public String doLogout() throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("In doLogout()");
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
            .getRequestDispatcher("/logout");

    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
            (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    System.out.println("End doLogout()");
    return null;
}
```

I had to use `/logout` instead of `/j_spring_security_logout`

Answer (score 2):

If CSRF enabled, you must [logout with a POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604457/1199132). You need to wrap it in a standard HTML form instead:

```
<form action="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

For using a link instead of a button, you'll need to write some javascript in order to make the link submit the form. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get).

Comment: I didn't try what you stated above, but your way should also work.

Comment: JSF comes with it's own CSRF protection so spring security CSRF protection should be disabled.

Comment: @Michal JSF adds CSRF protection as long as you use JSF itself to do the request.. That would involve calling a managed bean method to perform the logout, not the Spring security logout endpoint directly, the way the OP is doing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript solution for Spring Security 4 + CSRF + JSF:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout').submit();">Logout</a>
 <form action="logout" id="logout" method="post">                           
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" 
   value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```