# spring security logout not hitting success-handler-ref

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and spring-security 4.0.1.RELEASE
I have the following configuration

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint"  create-session="ifRequired" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAuthority('Admin')" />
        <custom-filter before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"  ref="loginTokenFilter" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/noaccess.html"/>
        <headers>
            <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
        </headers>
    </http>
```

And my logout success handler is

```
@Component("logoutSuccessHandler")
    public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogoutSuccessHandler.class);

    private final MyRedirectHandler redirectHandler;

    @Autowired
    public MyLogoutSuccessHandler(
            MyRedirectHandler redirectHandler) {
        this.redirectHandler = redirectHandler;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug("Won't redirect");
            return;
        }

        redirectHandler.redirectToLogin(request, response, true);
    }
}
```

Login is working great, but logout is not. I put a breakpoint into MyLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess()
and called http://localhost:8080/myapp/logout from browser. The success-handler wasn't called.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I provide specific @RequestMapping for "/logout" path?

in web.xml I have the following

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: is CSRF on? You need to POST the logout form if it is...

Comment: not familiar with CSRF so can not tell for sure... regarding POST, I am currently sending only a GET request. If POST is needed, should there be any specific data in POST body too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Spring security enables CSRF and logout MUST be a POST request as it expects a csrf token.
Check the [Spring CSRF documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html)..
Another similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604064/spring-security-logout-goes-to-j-spring-security-logout)

You can switchoff CSRF like this in your config if you want logout to work with a GET request..

```
<http auto-config="false">
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
```

if you dont want to switchoff CSRF, you must POST logout like this

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```